# AWS S3 php api : How to get url after file upload?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used aws sdk (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php).

code

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => $file,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
));
```

It's work well but i have a question:

1. How to get the url after file upload successful.

Thanks.

Comment: http://s3.amazonaws.com/YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/YOUR-FILE-NAME

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is returned in the response. See the [API docs for putObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject).

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'Body'   => $file,
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
));

$url = $result['ObjectURL'];
```

You can also use the `getObjectUrl()` method to get the URL.

```
$url = $client->getObjectUrl($bucket, $key);
```

Answer (score 6):

The result returned is an instance of Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model.

To get the url just use the get method provided by that class.

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'Body'   => $file,
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
));

$url = $result->get('ObjectURL');
```

Comment: this is more elegant, although the key we need to get is correctly 'ObjectURL', to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The object URL is available in the `$result` variable that is returned in your function call.

To access the object URL do this:

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'Body'   => $file,
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
));
$data=$result->toArray();
$object_url=$data['ObjectURL'];
```

Comment: I couldn't Malcolm Diggs solution to work, not sure if the API has changed since :)

Comment: Use $result->get('ObjectURL') now.